# Unity text not updating (lives counter)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to update the lives of my player in a brick breaker game, however I find myself unable to update the text UI responsible for displaying the score (it always displays 3 lives remaining).
Is there any way to fix this issue?

Here is the relevant code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    int lives;
    public bool isDead;
    public GameObject[] bricks;
    int numberBricks;
    public Text livesText;

   
    private void Start()
    {
        isDead = false;
        lives = 3;
        livesText.text = "lives left: " + lives.ToString();
        Debug.Log(lives);
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        livesText.text = "lives left: " + lives.ToString();
        numberBricks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("brick").Length;
        if (numberBricks == 0) {
            passLevel();
        }
    }
    private void passLevel() {

    }
    public void ReduceHealth() {
        lives--;
        Debug.Log(lives);


    }
    public void CheckDeath() {
        if (lives == 0) {
            isDead = true;
        }
    }
}
```

the ReduceHealth() function is called at

```
Ball.cs 
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    Vector3 Direction;
    int speedFactor;
    float minX;
    float maxX;
    float additionalForce;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public GameObject paddle;
    public AudioSource collisionSound;
    public GameObject gameManager;
    GameManager gm;

   
    void Start()
    {
        float sign = Mathf.Sign(Random.Range(-1,1));
        minX = -10f * sign;
        maxX = -2f * sign;

        Direction.x = Random.Range(minX,maxX) ;
        Direction.y = -40f;
        speedFactor = 1;
        
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        gm = gameManager.GetComponent<GameManager>();


    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       transform.position += Direction * speedFactor * Time.deltaTime;
    }  

    void Reset() {
        transform.position = new Vector3(0.14f,-4.58f,0f);
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" || other.gameObject.tag == "border-vertical") {
            Direction.y *=-1;
        } else if(other.gameObject.tag=="border-bottom") {
            gm.ReduceHealth();
            Reset();
        }else {
            Direction.x *= -1;
        }
    


    }
}
```

and here is the Screenshot of my inspector (GameManager object)

[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From the code you showed, the lives variable is not changing so its remains 3. In function ReduceHealth, you decrease the lives variable but in the code, you put here it seems you never called that function. Note Suggestion it not good Practice to update that text in the update function, update that text only when that lives variable is changes.

Comment: I see you are using a ReduceHealth() function to reduce lives. Now, I guess this is not the whole code and you have just shown the GameManager Script, I don't know if ReduceHealth function is being called or not(which it should if you want the lives to reduce). Also, you should not update your text in update that's a really bad practice why not move the updating of text to a different function like something called UpdateLivesUI() and call it in reduce health or any other place where your lives variable is changing.

Comment: @Jaimin l ah yeah, I forgot to post the other code but I did call the function, and it was working just fine when I debug logged it. That is not the issue. The issue is that the text itself wont update.

Comment: @Kushalagrawal ^

Comment: @KevinH So you are sure that lives variable is being updated and ReduceHealth is being called?? it's just that the native UI text is not being updated. That's okay I guess try moving
livesText.text thing in the reduce health function.

Comment: @Kushalagrawal nah, still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the function `ReduceHealth()` has no references. I created a `button` to see if the lives are reduced or not, it's working. Here is an attached image of [`OnClick()` in button inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRi32.png)

**A few tips**

- It is not a good practice to update the `text` in `Update` function, instead do it in the function where the value of `lives` is changing. Also check if the `lives == 0` in the same function only, there is no need for the function `CheckDeath()`.

  ```
   public void ReduceHealth() {
       lives--;
       livesText.text = "lives left: " + lives.ToString();

       if (lives == 0) {
           isDead = true;
       }
   }
  ```
- It is also not a good practice to keep checking the length of the number of bricks at every frame, instead have a check for it in whichever function the breaking of bricks is dealt with.
  For eg when the health of the brick reaches zero, get a reference to the `GameManager` script and do the length check there.

Comment: I appreciate the answer and advice for best practices, but there are references and the integer itself is being changed, however I couldnt change the text for some reason.

Comment: I have updated the post to show the full code for my Ball.cs script.

Comment: Are you sure you referenced the correct `Text` game object?. If possible, can you post your project GitHub link? I'd like to see the issue myself

Comment: sure i'll notify you in a bit @GeekyQuentin

Comment: @KevinH, you haven't notified me yet :D